# Navigation bar item tappable area cut when using offset

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, consider this navigation bar:

[image]

Here is how the trailing `.navigationBarItems` are declared:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Button(action: {
        self.addListModal = true
    }, label: {
        NavBarImage(image: "plus")
    })
    // more buttons here
```

Here is the `NavBarImage` struct:

```
struct NavBarImage: View {
    var image: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(width: 40, height: 45)
            Image(systemName: image)
        }
    }
}
```

The red is there so I can see what SHOULD be the tappable area for each button. This `ZStack` with a `Rectangle` idea was introduced to me as a way to make the images easier to tap.

Now, I wanted to shift the items to the right so they are more in line with the list content below. I tried adding an `.offset` to my `HStack`:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    // buttons
}
.offset(x: 15, y: 0)
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

So this looks perfect to me. The problem, however, is the right-most navigation button's tappable area is cut off on the right.

I've illustrated the cutting off of the tappable area in green, here:

[image]

The green area of said button no longer registers taps whatsoever.

I've tried using a negative trailing `.padding` on the `HStack` instead, and it made no difference. Is there a way I can correct this, perhaps by using some `UINavigationBar` declaration in the `init()` of my content view?

**Edit:**

I just tried adding `.accessibility` to the `Rectangle` and the result is the same:

```
Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red)
    .accessibility(label: Text(image))
    .frame(width: 40, height: 45)
```

Comment: Did you try to use the modifier .contentShape to alter the tap-able area ?

Comment: @stardust4891 Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I've been using SwiftUI since day 1, and struggling with this issue ever since. It seems like in SwiftUI there is now way to have tappable content at the very edge of the screen. In one of my apps this drove me so crazy that I actually used a UIKit `UINavigationController` inside a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, and it fixed the problem, but it's a massive pain.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use instead

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    // buttons
}
.padding(.trailing, 15)
```