# Hard to tap button in SwiftUI navigation bar items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `NavigationView` with a `Button` as leading navigation bar item. It seems the button action is fired only when user taps inside that little `Image`. Can I make the tappable area bigger, without affecting the height of the navigation bar?

I tried adding `.frame` to the `Image`, but that made the navigation bar too big.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Foo")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("tapped")
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        }
                    })
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the reason & solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492031/12299030)

Comment: Or could using `.imageScale(.large)` and/or `.padding()` help?

Comment: You can use `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to preserve the size but have the hit box be a lot bigger.

Comment: @cbjeukendrup `.imageScale(.large)` worked for me. You can put it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(One of) the following modifiers could help:

```
.imageScale(.large)
```

A image from SFSymbols has three sizes:

- `.small` for when using inline with text
- `.medium` for use as an icon
- `.large` for use as a button in a nav bar or bottom bar

---

```
.padding()
```

Adds padding around the image. The padding should also be tappable.

Comment: How to you solve the gap that is created? It is not de "default" position...

Comment: @LorisFoe Do you mean when using `padding`? I think I have to know a bit more about your particular case to give a good answer. Maybe `.offset(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)` could do something?

Comment: Simply make a navigation view and  put in `.navigationBarItems(trailing :` an `Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.large).padding()` and you will see the bug I am talking about. And yes maybe an offset could work, but how much is x? What is the default padding value that we will to retract...?

Comment: @LorisFoe I see what you mean. Couple of things you could consider: 1. Maybe it's already enough to do *only* `.imageScale(.large)` and leave the padding away. 2. You can add padding at only *specified edges* (for example: `.padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])`. 3. You can set a *specified amount* of padding and use offset, like so: `.padding(8.0).offset(x: 8.0)`. You could also check out [this page](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-spacing-around-individual-views-using-padding) for more examples. Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with the plus icon is that I really need padding on each side otherwise people must click at pixel precision on the blue part of the plus. But your hack of padding and offsetting the same value seems to be a good solution. Thx

Comment: Using padding and offset puts the nav bar button in visually the right place, but I find if you are tapping at the very edge of the screen (in the padding/offset area) it still doesn't register as a tap. It seems like with SwiftUI there is a hard limit on having tappable nav bar content right at the very right edge of the screen. I see someone else documented this behaviour here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847764/navigation-bar-item-tappable-area-cut-when-using-offset

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Foo")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("tapped")
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "info.circle").imageScale(.large) //Here is the change in image scale property
                        }
                    })
            }
    }
}
```

Happy Coding...